# Magento 2 shipping method is not overriding

Tags: magento2, overrides, shipment, ups

I am trying to override UPS shipping method. But it is not override.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier" />    
</config>
```

**Carrier.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
{

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $this->setRequest($request);
        if (!$this->canCollectRates()) {
            return $this->getErrorMessage();
        }

        $this->setRequest($request);
        $this->_result = $this->_getQuotes();
        $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);
        //$result = $this->enableShipping();
        //return $result;
        // custom logic code
       return $this->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: (the first file is `di.xml` )

Answer (score 0):

I have overwrite same way, only just include this

Replace

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model; class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
```

To

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier
```